# Issues trying to access an associative array converted from JSON in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, associative-array

I'm working on a Laravel project that implements [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form) and I need to convert the values saved in the database to an associative array so I can pluck certain values from it. However I am getting strange results when doing so.

Here is the code I use to grab the JSON data from the table and then convert to an array:

```
$form = Form::where('id', $formId)->get();

$converted = json_decode($form[0]->form_data, true);
$formArray = print_r($converted, 1);

return $formArray;
```

For testing purposes I am simply rendering the data in the browser.

The result from the above return is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1.1] => New
            [1.2] => Ms
            [1.3] => Isobel Fleming
            [1.4] => Array
                (
                    [uprn] => 52375918
                    [address_1] => Fake Street
                    [address_2] => 
                    [address_3] => 
                    [town_city] => BRISTOL
                    [postcode] => BS1 3KE
                )

            [1.5] => 0129711011
            [1.6] => 0800999111
            [1.7] => 0781100022
            [1.8] => isobelfleming@jourrapide.com

        )
)
```

which is great. However when I try and access anything from it like:

```
return $formData[1][1.1]
```

I get:

> String offset cast occurred

If I try using a string:

```
return $formData[1]['1.1']
```

I get:

> Illegal string offset '1.1'

So I am not sure what to do to access this data. The problem is, although it's not ideal to have the associate keys with decimals in them, this is the way the schema is set up and it's several thousand lines long - this is just a snippet of the form data.

Is there anything that can be done in order to get the data from this array?

Comment: You need to wrap the keys with single or double-quotes. something like this ["1.1"]. but it should work even if you don't wrap it with quotes.

Comment: Yep I already tried that (as per the second example I gave above)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It seems like the following line was the problem:

```
print_r($converted, 1);
```

It didn't need to be printed as an array, I should have just used the `$converted` variable to access the data like so:

```
return $converted[1]['1.1'];
```